# simple Javascript loop does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, loops

can someone explain why this loop does not output "i" in order "0 2 4 6 8 10", but instead it outputs "0 2 6 12 20 30 42 56 72 90" ?

```
  let nmb = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<50; i+=2){
      nmb+=i;
        document.write(nmb + " ");
    }
```

Comment: "_this loop does not output "i" in order_" It doesn't ouput `i` at all. You are printing `nmb` which adds `i` to its previous value.

Comment: In any programming language loops work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
 let nmb = 0;
 for(let i=0; i<50; i+=2){
     nmb+=2;
     document.write(nmb + " ");
 }
```

This should solve the problem. The thing is, in your current solution, you are adding i number to the sum. So you add **i=2** to nmb, nmb = 2. Then you add **i=4** to nmb, nmb = 6, then you add **i=6**, nmb = 12 etc...
You want to add constant value which is **2**, not **i** value.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is already incrementing `i` by 2 which is the number you want to display, making the `nmb` variable unnecessary.  So just write out `i`:

```js
for(let i=0; i<50; i+=2){
    document.write(i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always adding i instead of 2 to your sum.

You could just print i directly

```
 for(let i=0; i<50; i+=2){
    document.write(i + " ");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something with Array.from, but this was the closest I got

```js
let x = [], r = 25, i = 0;
while (x.push(i += 2) < r);
console.log(x.join(","))
```